# Cocoa Mac OS X application bundling 1000 images

Tags: macos, cocoa

We have a Cocoa Mac OS X application in which we want to bundle around 500 images. Each image is around 10kb so size isn't a problem.

These images are not exactly resources in the app, they are sample images.

Basically, we have simple button that would let the user copy these images to a directory.

The solution also needs to be "dump in, dump out" -- so we don't want to store individual image file names somewhere in our application; we just want to have a directory of images that can be copied.

How do I package these into my application?

The question turns into: **How do I make a directory resource containing the images.**

In our case everything gets flattened into the MyApp.app/Contents/Resources and this approach would require us to put image names in the app so that we can copy those.

Comment: "How do I package these into my application?" The same way you package anything. Basically, they _are_ resources in the app. To say they are not is just silly. Put them in the app bundle and give the user a button that lets the user copy them to somewhere else. No problem.

Comment: @matt The solution also needs to be "dump in, dump out" -- so we don't want to store individual image file names somewhere in our application; we just want to have a directory of images .

Comment: So why does that make what I said wrong? You can put a directory of images in your app bundle, and copy it (or its contents) wherever the user says or wherever you want, badda bing badda boom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the images into a folder. Drag the folder into your project in Xcode. In the resulting dialog, make sure you copy, make sure you create a *folder reference*, and make sure you add to your app target. Done. Now the folder is part of your app bundle and you can refer to it from your code without knowing anything about its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/Library/Application Support` is for support files that, if deleted, would not affect the execution of an application. I would suggest this is ideal for your product's sample images.

As [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) states for `Application Support`:

> Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources that are managed by the app. An app might use this directory to store a modifiable copy of resources contained initially in the app’s bundle.

So, use [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) / [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html) to install them to `/Library/Application Support/<ProductName>/`

Answer (score 0):

Because size is not an issue, you can just put all your sample images in separate Asset Catalog file.